# Bash script, please help me to make it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops

I want to make bash script...

and the result :

```
Row 1 : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Row 2 : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Row 3 : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Row 4 : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Row 5 : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Row 6 : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

can you help me...?

I made like this :

```
  for i {1..6}
  do
    for j {1..10}
    do
      list=$j
    done
    echo "Row $i = $list"
  done
```

Comment: I already edit my post....can you look at again?

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

```
$ seq -f "Row %g : $(seq -s' ' 10)" 6
Row 1 : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Row 2 : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Row 3 : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Row 4 : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Row 5 : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Row 6 : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
$
```

---

Given the constraint that you must use for-loops, you should be able to fix this with the help of the other answers.

To help you debug this sort of thing again in the future, you can add `set -x` to the top of your script (under `#!/bin/bash`).  This will turn on a bunch of debugging output which will help you understand what the script is doing and what you need to do to make it do what you want.

[The set builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin)

Comment: hmmm...
I want to make bash script with for loop...

Comment: @user2467583 - you should edit your question to indicate that constraint

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code.

Your `for` loop syntax is incorrect - you are missing `in` :: `for i in {1..6}`.

You are replacing the value of `list` instead of appending the next number :: `list="$list$j "`.

You need to reset the value of `list` for each row :: `list=""`

```
for i in {1..6}
do
  list=""
  for j in {1..10}
  do
    list="$list$j "
  done
  echo "Row $i = $list"
done
```